# Does the background of the title crawl change across the films?

Tags: star-wars

All of the *Star Wars* films open with a title crawl against a starry backdrop, and then a pan downwards onto whatever setting has the privilege of hosting the opening scene. Since the films don't all start in the exact same place, do the stars change to reflect the different locations?

Comment: Given that the text's shape and color varied from movie to movie, I'd be way surprised if the stars were consistent.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, the star field in the background changed. Compare the following screenshots, from [starwars.com](http://www.starwars.com/search?q=crawl&f%5Bsearch_section%5D=Video).

[image: Episode I]
[image: Episode II]
[image: Episode III]
[image: Episode IV]
[image: Episode V]
[image: Episode VI]